# Does GoDaddy.com offer an online HTML editor?

Tags: godaddy

I logged in my GoDaddy account where to access my website but was unable to find any html editor.

Although I found the domain manager, I could not get any further, do godaddy provide this service or should I look elsewhere for tools.

Comment: By HTML editor you mean WYSIWYG ? Please edit your question to be more accurate on your needs.

Comment: Not WYSIWYG, just any editor where I can edit my code on the site. All other host provides file manager where you can select a file and edit it directly on the site.

Comment: Not all hosts do this. I've actually found it to be rare among the ones I've encountered. The WebSite Tonight builder does also have HTML editing available(answer edited).

Comment: There are countless php scripts that will let you do this. If you don't like GoDaddy's file manager, install your own.

Answer (score 4):

The only site builder I'm aware of them offering is part of their [WebSite Tonight](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/website-builder.aspx?ci=9028) product, which integrates hosting also. There's not just an application you can launch from your "regular" hosting plan. (A one-page version of this is offered under the other plans, but that doesn't seem to be what you're after.)

The site builder isn't only WYSIWYG, but allows direct editing of the HTML source; check the features tab.

Comment: Can someone confirm this. They do have file manager and you can edit the file directly?

Answer (score 3):

I googled your exact question and it seems that godaddy does not provide an html editor, just a site builder. So to answer your question : you will have to look elsewhere

[Here is the link for this question on the Go Daddy Support site](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/html-editor-questions)

Comment: I am not sure if he is talking about live editor or godaddy changes it after uploaded. BTW, I googled this question before I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy has a code editor. Select the file in the list and click on code then edit then save.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in site builder offered by godaddy.com

Comment: Can you give more details such as how you would get to it, the major features, or a link to documentation?